# MySQL REGEXP - Where the column contains the regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex

So I have a table called "lu_regex" with a column called "regex"

```
 Select * from lu_regex; 

 athedsl-\d+
 i5[93][0-9a-fA-F]+\.versa
 5ac[a-f0-9]+.+sky
```

The table contains 1000's of rows, with various Regular Expressions syntax, i'm just showing three in this example.

Now I'm trying to take user input and match that input against the rows in the table.  So I'm doing this.

```
SELECT * FROM lu_regex where '5aca3a11.bb.sky.comr' regexp regex;

regex
5ac[a-f0-9]+.+sky

1 row returned.
```

I'm getting back what I expected, with that query, then I try this one.

```
SELECT * FROM lu_regex where 'athedsl-07371.home.otenet.gr' regexp regex;

 0 rows returned.
```

It should match on "athedsl-\d+", but i'm assuming it has something to do with the "\d". I even tried adding this to the database "athedsl-\\d+" and that didn't cause a match either.

I'm trying to stick to a MySQL solution, what am I doing wrong, this should be possible.

Comment: As a first try to confirm/infirm your suspiscion, you might replace `athedsl-\d+` by `athedsl-[0-9]+`.

Comment: It matches `athedsl-[0-9]+` when replaced.

Comment: So the issue is really where you suspected: `\d` seems not to work. I don't see why, just now, but I'll try to find something... If I don't come back, you'll know I was not lucky :)

Comment: Apparently MySql doesn't know this kind of class: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp. Alternatively you may use `[[:digit:]]+`.  So the more simple way is to keep merely `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this link, it looks like a bug that hasn't been fixed. It was verified in 2013.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70413

**Bug #70413    \d is not working in REGEXP for a MySQL query**

I think the solution is going to be is to replace all \d with [0-9]

Comment: It's not a bug.  The bug report seems to be incorrectly marked as verified; there are different dialects of regular expressions.  MySQL uses `[[:digit:]]`, not `\d`.  This is documented behavior: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html